# My if statement is not executing, how can I solve this?

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, javafx, logic

I am making a BlackJack game in JavaFX. So far, everything is smooth. The only thing missing is that the game should stop and the player should bust when the total value of cards is over 21, like the real game. I added an if statement in my code. Good new is, the if statement executes. Bad news is, it executes AFTER the total value is over 21. So the player can still hit when the value is 23. The if statement will then not execute. It executes when the player hits again, and 23 becomes 25 for example.

I hope I explained it well, otherwise please give me feedback.

Here is my code:

```
    public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private int playerValue, dealerValue, playerTotal, dealerTotal;





    Random ran = new Random();
    @FXML
    private TextArea dealerArea;
    @FXML
    private TextArea playerArea;
    @FXML
    private Label labelPlayerTotal;
    @FXML
    private Label labelDealerTotal;
    @FXML
    private Label labelWinner;
    @FXML
    private Button hitButton;
    @FXML
    private Button stayButton;
    @FXML
    private Button replayButton;





    public void drawCardForPlayer(ActionEvent event) {

        stayButton.setDisable(false);
        playerValue = ran.nextInt(14);

        while (playerValue <=1) {
            playerValue = ran.nextInt(14);
        }
        ######################################
        // I created this broken if statement
        if (playerTotal >21) {

            labelWinner.setText("You busted, dealer won!");
            hitButton.setDisable(true);
            stayButton.setDisable(true);

        }
        #########################
        switch (playerValue) {

        case 2:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawTwo());
            playerTotal = 2 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;

        case 3:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawThree()); 
            playerTotal = 3 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;

        case 4:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawFour()); 
            playerTotal = 4 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;

        case 5:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawFive()); 
            playerTotal = 5 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;

        case 6:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawSix()); 
            playerTotal = 6 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;

        case 7:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawSeven());
            playerTotal = 7 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;

        case 8:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawEight()); 
            playerTotal = 8 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;

        case 9:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawNine());
            playerTotal = 9 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;

        case 11:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawJack());
            playerTotal = 10 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;
        case 12:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawQueen()); 
            playerTotal = 10 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;
        case 13:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawKing());
            playerTotal = 10 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;
        case 14:
            playerArea.appendText("\t" + Deck.drawAce());
            playerTotal = 11 + playerTotal;
            labelPlayerTotal.setText("Playertotal:" + playerTotal);
            break;

            default:
            break;

        }



    }
   }
   }
```

I debugged it and realized that the value of playerTotal is 0 at first, and the value of playerTotal is only initialized in the switch-case, and that is causing the issue. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`playerTotal` isn't updated until your `switch`. Make your `if` statement checks for `PlayerTotal + playerValue > 21`

Comment: @Smile If this answers your question, you should mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your if condition to be before the code that gets a new random card.

```
    if (playerTotal >21) {

        labelWinner.setText("You busted, dealer won!");
        hitButton.setDisable(true);
        stayButton.setDisable(true);

    }

    stayButton.setDisable(false);
    playerValue = ran.nextInt(14);

    while (playerValue <=1) {
        playerValue = ran.nextInt(14);
    }
    switch (playerValue) {
        ....
```

Comment: I tried that, the value of playerTotal is still initially 0.

Comment: @Smile It should be initially 0 (before any cards are added). The important thing is that before getting a new card you test that the current total doesn't exceed 21.